# Issues with normal of a line.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

I think I am doing something wrong here but think about this simple thought if we have a 2D line in a Cartesian plane, say $2x+y=5$, and $P=(0,5)$ is a point on the line. We can say that
$$
n·x = n·p
$$
Saying that $n$ is the normal to the line $2x+y=5$. If $n = [a,b]$ and $x = [x,y]$ (point X and P being on the line $2x+y=5$), we say that
$$
[a,b] ·[x,y] = n·p
$$
and both *n·p* and *n·x* are 0 as both p and x are orthogonal to the normal N. So from the equation above we can make
$$
[a,b] · [x,y] = 0
$$
or
$$
ax+by = 0
$$
so does this mean that $ax+by$ always $= 0$? That wouldn't make sense, would it? What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is confusion between position vectors and free vectors. Points $p$ and $x$ are position vectors; with reference to the origin $(0,0)$. They are fixed on the plane.

$n$ is a free vector. It can be moved around (but its direction stays the same).

So $n\cdot x = n\cdot p \Rightarrow n\cdot(x-p)=0$

and not $n\cdot x =0= n\cdot p$! $n\cdot x$ is non-zero in general, as is $n\cdot p$. Position vector $x$ is pointing from $(0,0)$ to point $x$, which need not be orthogonal to $n$.

$n\cdot(x-p)=0$ means $x-p$ is a vector along the given line and $n$ is of course, orthogonal to it.